# Can I use papermill for aws sagemaker notebooks to create excel reports?

Tags: excel, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, papermill

So I know I can use papermill to run jupyter notebooks in an automated way, but if I use an AWS Sagemaker notebook and I create excel reports with jupyter notebook (exporting to excel).
How do I find my excel files? Because I can only give a notebook as an output file or not?

I'm planning to use the solution below:
https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-run-notebook/blob/master/QuickStart.md#using-existing-aws-primitives

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the specific location to save the exported notebook like S3 bucket.
You can try papermill rclone which runs as subprocess and you can hardcode the location or pass dynamically the locations.
Please refer the link for more details about rclone 
https://pbpython.com/papermil-rclone-report-2.html
[image]

[image]